# knockout binding for each trying to manipulate single elements in the for each loop

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In a for each binding, how would I go about trying to toggle single p rather than all the P elements in the for each binding, hope that's not too confusing :)

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">

<p data-bind="click:somefunction" class="p1"> </P>

<p class="p2"> </p>

</div>

 var shellModel = {
  observables .....,
     somefunction: function() {

      ....here i need to toggle p2 (display on/off) not all though, only the one click on or rather the p below
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `$index` to your function to know which one was clicked and act accordingly:

```
<p data-bind="click:somefunction($index)" class="p1"> </P>

self.someFunction = function(index){
    alert("Click on item number: " + index); 
};
```

Comment: I was just about well ust  have added a custom binding http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/8KJD3/ but your method is a bit more succint as I dont need to try and find the ID from the array, very nice, thankyou Diana.

Answer (score 1):

If changing visibility is part of your view then it should be part of your view model.

Once you do that, things will fall into place on their own.

```
function ItemViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.isExpanded = ko.observable(false);

    self.toggle = function () {
        self.isExpanded(!self.isExpanded());
    };
}

function MainVievModel() {
    var self.this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([ /* instances of ItemViewModel*/]);
}
```

and

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <p data-bind="click: toggle" class="p1"> </p>
    <p data-bind="visible: isExpanded" class="p2"></p>
</div>
```

Stop thinking *"I want to toggle the second `<p>`"*. Think *"I want to toggle the item between expanded state and collapsed state."* and after that works make a visual representation of it, for example using the `visual` binding.

Comment: Tomalak, I am using visible binding, and have used something similar elswhere in the App, and it works great but what about when there's a list of items, and there's many p2 , how can I used the visible binding as it turns all the p2's on, side question  self.isExpanded(!self.isExpanded()); just reverses the value, cool way, I'd be doing if's there usually, thx

Comment: You still think about your `div.p2`. Don't do that. If there are many *items* then write a function that iterates those *items* and toggles their `isExpanded` properties (in my sample it would be a method of the `MainVievModel`). The fact that a `div.p2` appears when `isExpanded` is true is secondary. That's a purely property of your *view*. Your task is to manipulate the view *model*.

Comment: I see what you mean as the for each is an array, the ixexpanded property is really unique, having a mess now, thanks for the pointers !